# SSRS 2017 weird behavior with Column Chart for Custom Label Text on Horizontal Axis

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I am experiencing weird behavior with SSRS 2017 column charts. Please see below scenario and sql script provided for the same.

**SSRS Chart Type - Column**

**Category Group** - Group on ReportType, Label - ReportCustomText

**Horizontal Axis Option**

Axis Type - Category and other default options

**Series Group**

```
     Group 1 = ReportType - Group on ReportType, Label - ReportCustomText
     Group 2 = EntityName - Group on EntityName, Label - EntityName
```

**Series Values** -

```
     Value Field - EntityValue
     CategoryField - ReportCustomText
```

Horizontal axis properties are kept as default. In this report, I will have maximum three data points on x axis. SSRS shows weird values for only below scenario.

Three Data Points

```
ReportType=1 Custom Label Text = 0 - 10
ReportType=2 Custom Label Text = 11 - 20
ReportType=3 Custom Label Text = 21 - 31
```

Whenever we've values for **Second Data Point only**( i.e. for Report Type =2), SSRS Chart display random data value instead of specified label text. It works correctly if we've data points for Report Type value 1 or 2.

It seems like a bug introduced in SSRS 2017 but I would really appreciate if you can take a look at this issue.

**SQL Sample Data**

```
  Create Table #ReportResult      
  (      
   ReportType SMALLINT,      
   EntityName Varchar(64),      
   EntityValue INT,  
   EffectiveMonth varchar(32),
   ReportSeriesCount TINYINT,
   ReportTypeCount SMALLINT,
   ReportTypeRank TINYINT,
   ReportCustomText varchar(32)

  )    

   Insert Into #ReportResult (ReportType,EntityName,EntityValue,EffectiveMonth,ReportCustomText) Values
   (2,'Report Rule - 11',   12, NULL,'11 - 20'),
(2,'Report Rule - 22',  11, NULL,'11 - 20'), 
(2,'Report Rule - 33',  5,  NULL,'11 - 20') 

SELECT * FROM #ReportResult

DROP TABLE #ReportResult
```

**Screenshot for the chart**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your horizontal Axis properties.

I can reproduce your results if I change the Axis Type to `Scalar (Numbers/Dates)`.

If I leave it as the default setting `Category` then the I get the expected value `11-20`.

Comment: Alan, thanks for your response. Actually I've kept Horizontal Axis Type as Category with default settings.